# sprites movement estrangely

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'm new to python, but I'm already learning `pygame`, and I have this problem that when the player goes up or down the sprite doesn't follow it, it appears in the middle of the right wall and moves to the center, with the right animation that I would like it to be, and if you stop pressing the button, the player appears where he should have been if he had moved right.
it seems that it is a problem of the draw function but I already edited what was possible but nothing has changed, hopefully, someone can help me.

here is the code:

```py
class player(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 10
        self.isJump = False
        self.left = False
        self.up = False
        self.dawn = False
        self.right = False
        self.walkCount = 0

    def draw(self, win):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 27:
            self.walkCount = 0

        if self.left:
            win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.right:
            win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.dawn:
            win.blit(walkDawn[self.walkCount//3],(self.y,self.x))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.up:
            win.blit(walkUp[self.walkCount//3], (self.y,self.x))
            self.walkCount += 1
        else:
            win.blit(char, (self.x,self.y))
```

Comment: *"it seems that it is a problem of the draw function"* Why do you think that. It doesn't seem so. But this is impossible to say, without seeing the code which changes the player attributes for position and direction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the draw function, in the walkup and walkdawn, needed to convert +=1 to -=1 and (self.y, self.x) needed to change the order, so now it is working as it need to work. But if some one know other answer to this problem I accept, thanks :).